# SASS/CSS background image preloading in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

```
body
    &:after
      content: url('image1.jpg') url('image2.jpg') url('image3.jpg') url('image4.jpg') 
      display:none
```

I'm using the code above to preload background images.  However, my display:none does not seem to work. All the images are being loaded and are visiable. Is this a browser specific thing? I'm using firefox 20 on mac or bad css/sass syntax? I need the solution to be multi-browser compatible. I just want all my images preloaded in a clean and simple way.

thank you

Comment: If your using the asset pipeline don't forget to use image-url helper instead of just url.

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: image-url is a helper that returns the full digested pass if I remember correctly, at least thats how it used to be set up. But thinking back on it they might have just made url be all encompassing. I still use image-url for images though, and font-url for fonts etc just in case.

Comment: good to know.  Althought, I'm reconsidering this css now, I read that some browsers will not even downlaod the image when display is set to none (display: none).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution:

I forgot to put a space between display and none

hence,

```
display:none
```

does not work, but

```
display: none
```

does work.

Sometimes it's the littlest things.